# why mysql deadlock happened?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, deadlock

I have a mysql table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idxvalue` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ukvalue` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_value` (`ukvalue`),
  KEY `idx_value` (`idxvalue`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And I insert 2 rows into the table:

```sql
insert into test (id, value, idxvalue, ukvalue) values (10, 1, 3, 3);
insert into test (id, value, idxvalue, ukvalue) values (20, 1, 3, 4);
```

Then I created a transaction (Transaction1):

```sql
> begin;

> insert into test (id, value, idxvalue, ukvalue) values (9, 1, 3, 3);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3' for key 'uk_value'

> delete from test where ukvalue = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then I created another transaction (Transaction2):

```sql
> insert into test (id, value, idxvalue, ukvalue) values (13, 1, 3, 3);
```

Then I went back to Transaction1, and ran:

```sql
> insert into test (id, value, idxvalue, ukvalue) values (14, 1, 3, 3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

> delete from test where ukvalue = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

At the same time, in Transaction2, I got:

```sql
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Why deadlock happened here?
Thanks

Environment:
mysql 5.7.28-0
linux ubuntu0.18.04.4

Answer (score 0):

Please check "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" to see details about the deadlock.

When you execute query "delete from test where ukvalue = 3", transaction 1 locks the index for ukvalue = 3 with lock with mode "X locks rec but not gap".

When you execute query "insert into test (id, value, idxvalue, ukvalue) values (13, 1, 3, 3)", transaction 2 starts waiting to get lock for index for ukvalue = 3 with with mode S. Transaction 2 is now waiting for transaction 1 to release the X lock.

When you execute the rest of the queries in transaction 1, the transaction 1 tries to get another lock for index for ukvalue = 3 with mode " locks gap before rec insert intention waiting". Transaction 1 is now waiting for transaction 2 to release the S lock.

Transaction 2 is now waiting for transaction 1, and transaction 1 is waiting for transaction 2. That's a deadlock.